# How Can I Print the names and ages of each employee who works in both the Hardware department and the Software department?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I wrote this query for print name and age of Employee that works in both the Hardware and Software department But it is not give me the right output !!?

```
create table emp1 
(
eID integer PRIMARY key ,
eNAME varchar2(30),
age integer ,
salary integer
);        
 create table works 
  (
  eID integer REFERENCES emp1(eID),
  dID integer REFERENCES dept(dID1),
  pct_time integer 
  );
 create table dept
(
dID1 integer UNIQUE,
dNAME VARCHAR2(30) ,
budget integer ,
managerID integer ,
PRIMARY key(dID1,managerID)
 );

select eNAME,age from emp1 , works where works.dID in(select dept.dID1 
from  dept where dNAME='Hardware');
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `EXISTS` and correlated subqueries to check if records exists mapping an employee to both software and hardware.

```
SELECT e.ename,
       e.age
       FROM emp1 e
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM works w
                                 INNER JOIN dept d
                                            ON d.did1 = w.did
                            WHERE d.name = 'Software')
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM works w
                                     INNER JOIN dept d
                                                ON d.did1 = w.did
                                WHERE d.name = 'Hardware');
```

Another method is to join the departments to the employees, filter for software or hardware and then `GROUP BY` the employee's attributes. If they work in both, the number of distinct department IDs has to be `2`. That can be checked in a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT e.name,
       e.age
       FROM emp1 e
            INNER JOIN works w
                       ON w.eid = e.eid
            INNER JOIN dept d
                       ON d.did1 = w.did
       WHERE d.dname IN ('Software',
                         'Hardware')
       GROUP BY e.ename,
                e.age
       HAVING count(DISTINCT d.did) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT** E.ename, E.age
**FROM** Emp E, Works W1, Works W2, Dept D1, Dept D2
**WHERE** E.eid = W1.eid AND W1.did = D1.did AND D1.dname = ‘Hardware’ AND
E.eid = W2.eid AND W2.did = D2.did AND D2.dname = ‘Software’

Comment: Can you please add some definition to your answer?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.